# Features are not visible in Visual Studio Team Services backlog

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I ran "Move to team project..." on an existing Epic.

The Epic moved to the target project but only one of the child Features is visible in the Backlog.
When I open the Epic I can see all the other child Features in the Related Work pane and I can drill down through them all the way to Tasks.

Features and Stories are not showing when selecting from the left hand side Epics/Features/Stories hierarchy.

How do I get my Features and Stories to display in the Backlog?

Comment: You need to also move all the child work items manually, check Luca's updated answer for details.

Comment: Do you solve the issue with Luca's solution?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**
You have to manually move all the linked Work Items as well.

If the linked work items are too many, I would create a query of type "Work Items and direct links" with the clause:

```
ID = <ID OF THE PARENT WORK ITEM>
```

Leave everything else as default.

Run the query and you would get the list of linked items.

Select all the linked work items (click on the first, and then on the last holding down the SHIFT key), right click on the selection and choose "Move to Team Project".

Comment: I couldn't edit the Area or Iteration fields in the work items.  In the drop down the current Area was the only item available.  The currently visible Work Items showed the current Area and the ones I could not see only showed the Area from where they were copied.